# SharePoint audit

Tags: 2007, administration, server-farm

What's the best approach for auditing a MOSS 2007 farm and ensuring it's correctly configured, which service accounts are in use.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to control SharePoint's build in auditing then you can consider a third party tool such as [this one](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/SharePoint-Audit/summary.aspx) (ours) or [this one](http://www.syntergy.com/products/sharepoint/more/audit/) (a competitor's).

However, it sounds that you want to audit the fact 'that the farm has been configured correctly'. You may want to try [Microsoft's best practices Analyser for SharePoint](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263211(office.12).aspx).

**Update:** [See this related question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13399/auditing-using-sharepoint-foundation-2010/13407#13407).

Answer (score 0):

I've not found a free tool that does it all. There are some commercial products that with some customisation could be used but in the interim I've used these

This can give some of the information you need:

http://spsfarmreport.codeplex.com/

Provides a report of server roles, content databases and accounts etc.

There is also the BPA:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=cb944b27-9d6b-4a1f-b3e1-778efda07df8&displaylang=en

And the SharePoint Administration Toolkit:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2009/08/27/3277616.aspx

Hope this helps.

Chris