# Find users activity in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I need to find the user activity in a SharePoint 2007 site such as viewing or downloading the document. How shall I do it?

Answer (score 3):

msdn: [Item-Level audit for developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb397403%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#MOSS2007ItemLevelAudit_BuiltinAuditSupinWSSandMOSS)
Because Windows SharePoint Services does not provide the functionality to see entries that are written to the audit log, a developer must write code to enable the Windows SharePoint Services audit logging facility. A developer must also supply code and a user interface to read entries from the audit log and display this data to the site’s users. The sample code that accompanies this article shows how to create this type of custom auditing solution.

Answer (score 3):

The Audit feature is there in Sharepoint 2007 foundation but there is  no user interface associated for auditing in Sharepoint 2007 or 2010.

You can use Powershell to get the desired results

Check this link(This applies to Sharepoint 2007 also)

[How do we activate auditing in SharePoint Foundation 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13399/how-do-we-activate-auditing-in-sharepoint-foundation-2010)

Answer (score 1):

Read the following article:
[Configure audit settings for a site collection](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-f5a346d0-ee0f-4412-a5e6-d9b5abaa1012)

Also, you can use 3-rd party solutions.

Comment: The portal is built on sharepoint 2007 foundation. I am not getting the 'Site collection audit settings'.